# Tool comparable to SoapUI for creating GUIs for functional testing of RESTful web services, without all the WSDL/schema nonsense

Tags: web-services, rest, user-interface, asp.net-web-api, functional-testing

*Apologies if this has already been covered in another question - there are a lot of questions (many with answers) about functionally testing REST services but this question is specifically geared towards allowing laypeople to create simple GUI interfaces to those services by mapping GUI controls to service inputs/outputs.*

Is there a tool out there, open-source, free, or commercial, that allows laypeople to create simple forms to functionally test REST services that are similar to SoapUI's forms for SOAP services? I realize there would not be WSDL involved, so the user would still need to do some work to get an endpoint set up to test.

Alternatively, are there any libraries available for Web API 2 that generate this sort of interface from the method signatures and routes?

I am looking for the easiest way to allow a tester to start functionally testing a web service, ideally with a little more GUI-ness than is provided by, say, Postman.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger is a simple yet powerful representation of your RESTful API. With the largest ecosystem of API tooling on the planet, thousands of developers are supporting Swagger in almost every modern programming language and deployment environment. With a Swagger-enabled API, you get interactive documentation, client SDK generation and discoverability.

http://swagger.io/